# Swift core data to custom UITableViewCell UILabel error

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, core-data

[Photo showing current error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ib3uJ.png)

I am new to working with TableViews. I have it setup to display tasks that are added from a TextField to a Tableview being saved in CoreData. My issue is now trying to have it put the content of the UITextField not in the default cell but a custom cell with a UILabel. Any help would be awesome thanks! Photo link above shows current error

Comment: add a code of Task class.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than the `Task` instance itself you have to assign a property with type `String` for example

```
... = tasks[indexPath.row].name
```

Replace `name` with the property you want to show.

Comment: ahh! Thank you so much